# Text content in listview not displaying C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview

I have a listview control and the text will not show up. I have tried 3 different implementations and I get the same result in each. The rows for the associated number of items will highlight, but the text is nowhere. I am using WPF and the text contents look like the following in the file I am reading in:

```
string1::string2
```

However, for testing purposes, I am not utilizing the file contents.

Tutorial I'm Using: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-with-gridview/

"1" and "2" were in there just to test.

[image]

## Code

```
        List<ServerData> items = new List<ServerData>();

        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null )
        {
            string[] serverData = Regex.Split(line, "::");
            items.Add(new ServerData() { IPAddress="1", ServerName="2" });
        }
        listServer.ItemsSource = items;
        file.Close();
```

....

```
public class ServerData
{
    public string IPAddress { get; set; }
    public string ServerName { get; set; }
}
```

## XAML

```
<ListView Margin="10,47,11,45.8" x:Name="listServer" Grid.RowSpan="2">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="IP Address" Width="218.4" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Server Name" Width="218.4" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Is this winforms? WPF? What does the contents of the file look like? Have you set up any databinding? It's not likely to automatically display the sub-properties of `ServerData'.

Comment: you need to add subitems of the listview, and by subitems i mean IPAddress and Servername as subitems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ListView Margin="10,47,11,45.8" x:Name="listServer" Grid.RowSpan="2">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="IP Address" Width="218.4" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Server Name" Width="218.4" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Here's your problem, you're binding the columns to `Name`, when instead it should be:

```
<ListView Margin="10,47,11,45.8" x:Name="listServer" Grid.RowSpan="2">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="IP Address" Width="218.4" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding IPAddress}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Server Name" Width="218.4" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ServerName}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: @ryan great, if you could accept it as the answer when you get a chance, that'd be brill.

Comment: Sure thing, give me 5 minutes :)